# Можно ли переформатировать файл .numbers в .csv-файл при помощи Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для дальнейшей работы с файлом мне было бы удобнее, если бы он был в .csv-формате а не в .numbers. Есть ли способ который мог бы конвертировать .numbers-файл в csv-формат  без потери или изменений в данных?

Comment: Зависит от того, что за формат такой .numbers

Comment: @insolor эпловский "эксель"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, можно воспользоваться библиотеками [numbers-parser](https://github.com/masaccio/numbers-parser) и `Pandas`. Там даже пример есть по ссылке:

```
# python3 -m pip install numbers-parser
from numbers_parser import Document
import pandas as pd

doc = Document("simple.numbers")
sheets = doc.sheets()
tables = sheets[0].tables()
data = tables[0].rows(values_only=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Ну и дальше экспортировать в `csv`:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```